# how in rstudio to send all code within if statement or function statement

Tags: r, rstudio

I have tried different shortcuts within the code>run region menu, but I can't seem to find a command that runs all code within a function or an if statement, so for very long functions I have to either highlight the whole function or used ctrl+enter multiple times. In Sublime Text for example using ctrl+enter sends the whole code section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl Alt F should do the trick

Comment: I tried that, it works but the cursor doesn't advance, is there a way to make it run the code and advance the cursor like crtl+enter does?

Comment: To the best of my (limited) knowledge, R doesn't have this functionality. However you could write each function in a separate r file, and flick between tabs. This might be a quicker way of operating, but it will depend on your application.

Comment: or use the sectioning feature of R studio,

Comment: eg type: `#### Section Name ####`

This is then navigable using the drop down box at the bottom, to flick to the next named section.